# Force show on modal from puppeteer

Tags: node.js, modal-dialog, puppeteer

I am working on a test tool using puppeteer.

Javascript code works but I need to execute it from puppeteer.

$('#myModal').modal('show') works from the console, but I am not able to get it working via page.$eval or similar calls.

I am lost. Please advice.

Thanks.

Rene

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using jQuery inside the page. The $ from jQuery and $eval form puppeteer has no connection.

Try the following [page.evaluate](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) which is kinda similar to running a code inside console,

```
page.evaluate(()=>$('#myModal').modal('show'))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Indeed I use jQuery inside the page.